# Photo Gallery in Android

Tags: android

I am trying implement a photo gallery similar to facebook in Android.

I was wondering where I could look for information on how to do this. I realize some of it is done using animations for example when you click on a photo the comments, share and next and previous buttons are all implemented using animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hacked a simple [android image gallery](https://github.com/alvinsj/android-image-gallery), it's on [github](https://github.com/alvinsj/android-image-gallery).

You can actually take a look, and get those codes you want, then build on top of it for more features.

For example, you can use [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) to specify what to do on single tap event, maybe to show the options to share, comments, browse next/previous photo etc. For animation, you can also add [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Animation) as transition when showing the options.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing but an OOM is thrown when running the app (E/dalvikvm-heap(25950): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation)