# All of pictures is on my phone gallery

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

Hi guys currently creating an application and i need help. When i install the app on my phone all of the pictures that i used is on my phone gallery how does that happen?

If i go to my phone/mobile gallery all of  the pictures are in there.

Hope someone can help me :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photo Gallery in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657613/photo-gallery-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when third party application creates a media file (say, photo), it has an option of sending `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` `Intent` which has a `Uri` pointing to a newly created file. The media scanner picks this `Intent`, parses the file, gets the metadata out of it and adds this file to the media content provider.
Later on, another application (say, Gallery app) can request media content provider to provide access to all files of some category, e.g. photos.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the images inside your project or do you get them from another source and save them to storage?
If it is the latter, then just save them to private internal storage.
maybe http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal might be of help?